# Scintilla Supports Unicode? What about SCI_GETCHARAT?

Tags: unicode, scintilla

Does Scintilla really support Unicode? If so, why does [`SCI_GETCHARAT`](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETCHARAT) return a `char` value (casted to `LRESULT`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [SCI_SETCODEPAGE docs](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETCODEPAGE)...

> Code page SC_CP_UTF8 (65001) sets Scintilla into Unicode mode with the document treated as a sequence of characters expressed in UTF-8. The text is converted to the platform's normal Unicode encoding before being drawn by the OS and thus can display Hebrew, Arabic, Cyrillic, and Han characters.

You will have to examine the byte you retrieve with SCI_GETCHARAT(pos) and, depending on the top bits of that, maybe read SCI_GETCHARAT(pos+1) and beyond in order to get the Unicode code point. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design).)

**Edit:**

For some C++ code that does this, see below (search for `SciMoz::GetWCharAt`):

http://vacuproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/npscimoz/npscimoz/oldsrc/trunk.nsSciMoz.cxx

Comment: +1 huh, interesting... doesn't that mean you can't randomly access a character, though? How does the editor work with large files then?

Comment: It probably does complicate that, although usually one would be working with caret or selection positions which would already have compensated for multibyte characters, presumably. As for your second question, I'm not sure I see a problem, but the [Scintilla source code](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html) would surely be enlightening :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was long time ago but if I remember well Scintilla is not a native Unicode application. Still it has **some** Unicode support.

First, the function name should `SCI_GETBYTEAT`, because it returns a byte from UTF-8 internal  buffer.

Also, the application has Unicode support for keybaord, so it has some Unicode support :)

Comment: Oh wow, I just saw your edit. +1 okay... but how does it open large files without random indexing?